# ISR entered without any enabled when no interrupt flag is set. Double firing?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, interrupt, cortex-m

​

I am using the ADC on my STM32L431 with both DMA and interruption. Everything works fine, except that the ISR is often entered with none of the enabled interrupt flag being set.​

Initial ISR code:

```
void ADC1_IRQHandler() 

{
  if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_JEOC(ADC1))
  {
      inj_buf[BL - DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR] = ADC1->JDR1;
  }
  else if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_OVR(ADC1))
  {
      LL_ADC_ClearFlag_OVR(ADC1);
  }
  else
  {
      __NOP();  //A breakpoint is set here and it is reached quite often
  }
}
```

Somebody pointed out in the post I posted on ST forum that this is caused by the program exiting ISR too soon, therefore the interrupt flag is not yet cleared, then the program would enter ISR again. As soon as the ISR entered the flag finally gets cleared.

Since then, I tried to fixed it by doing the following:

1.

```
void ADC1_IRQHandler() 
{

  if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_JEOC(ADC1))
  {
      inj_buf[BL - DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR] = ADC1->JDR1;
      __DSB();
  }
  else if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_OVR(ADC1))
  {
      LL_ADC_ClearFlag_OVR(ADC1);
      __DSB();
  }
  else
  {
      __NOP();
  }
}
```

2. void ADC1_IRQHandler()
   {
   if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_JEOC(ADC1))
   {
   inj_buf[BL - DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR] = ADC1->JDR1;
   loop_cnt++;                  //Read - Modify - Write
   if(loop_cnt >= 1024) loop_cnt = 0;
   }
   else if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_OVR(ADC1))
   {
   LL_ADC_ClearFlag_OVR(ADC1);
   loop_cnt++;
   loop_cnt--;
   }
   else
   {
   __NOP();
   }
   }
   According [to this article by ARM](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka003795/latest)
3. void ADC1_IRQHandler()
   {
   if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_JEOC(ADC1))
   {
   inj_buf[BL - DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR] = ADC1->JDR1;
   temp_isr = ADC1->ISR & 0x7FF;      //Read immediately after write
   }
   else if(LL_ADC_IsActiveFlag_OVR(ADC1))
   {
   LL_ADC_ClearFlag_OVR(ADC1);
   temp_isr = ADC1->ISR & 0x7FF;
   }
   else
   {
   __NOP();
   }
   }

According to [this post on a different forum](https://false.ekta.is/2012/06/interrupt-service-routines-double-firing-on-stm32/)

But none of them solved the issue.

Please help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment rather than an answer, but I don't quite have enough reputation to just comment. Anyway...

Why are you reading the ADC values in the ISR and storing them in a buffer, if you are DMAing the data anyway? This seems pointless and confused. Are you DMAing into SRAM, or into another peripheral?

If the answer is SRAM, these ISRs are not required. Disable interrupts for the ADC, and (maybe, or maybe not) enable them for the DMA.

Comment: I should've explained that, but I'm using both of them because there is problem with interleaved data from different channels when just using the DMA. Their order would get messed up after running for a while

Comment: @Zhi Maybe you should just try to fix the DMA problem then. If the order is getting messed up, I imagine that could only happen if there was an overrun. and I doubt an ISR-based solution could possibly be faster than DMA. As it stands, I don't think you've showed enough code to really figure anything out.